# An inequality involving a polynomial and its first and second derivative

Tags: polynomials, inequalities

Given a real polynomial $P(x)$ all whose roots are real,  it is not hard to show that
$$P(x)P''(x) \leq P'(x)^2 \, \, \, \,  (1).$$

Proof sketch: Assume that $P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-r_i)$. Look at $\log P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log (x-r_i)$ and take the second derivative of both sides.

One nice consequence of Inequality 1, is that if a polynomial $P(x)= a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ satisfies $2a_0a_2 > a_1^2 $ then $P(x)$ must have a complex root. To see this plug $x=0$ into the earlier inequality.

One might hope for a version of Inequality 1 which is true for all polynomials  with the left-hand side just a function of $P(x)$ and $P''(x)$,  and the right just a function of $P'(x)$, that works for all real numbers. But this cannot possibly be true because $P'(x)$ has no information about the constant term of $P(x)$.  However, it is true tat Inequality 1 is true for any polynomial provided $|x|$ is sufficiently large.

It also isn't too hard to show that if $Q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial that

$$Q(x)Q''(x) \leq \left(1+Q'(x)^2 + Q(0)^2\right)^2 \, \, \, \,  (2).$$

Together, Inequalities 1 and 2 motivate the following two questions.

1. Is there a function $f(n)$ such that for any real polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$, one has

$$P(x)P''(x) \leq (1+P'(x)^2 + P(0)^2)^{f(n)}. $$

Edit: This is trivially false for silly reasons as pointed out below. To make it non-trivial, here is question 1a)

1a) Is there a function $f(n)$ such that for any real polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$, one has

$$P(x)P''(x) \leq (2+P'(x)^2 + P(0)^2)^{f(n)}. $$

(Here 2 can be replaced with any number greater than 1 with a corresponding increase in $f(n)$).

My guess is that the answer to 1a is still no, but if there is such a function how slow a function can we make $f(n)$?

2. Is there a  function $f(n)$ such that the following  sort of inequality holds for any real polynomial of degree $n$:

$$P(x)P''(x) \leq \left(1+ P'(x)^2 + \sum_{i=0}^{f(n)} P(i)^2\right)^2.$$.

My guess here is that this should be the case, and that one can actually even have $f(n)$ here be linear, maybe something like $n+1$.

Comment: About Question 1: it may well happen that a polynomial $P(x)$ satisfies $P(0)= P'(1)=0$, $P(1)=1$ and $P''(1)=2$, say e.g. $P(x):=2x^3-5x^2+4x$. But then whatever is $f(n)$,  for $x=1$ the rhs is smaller than the lhs.

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks. That's a good point. So as written 1 is obviously false. Replacing 1 with some larger number solves that problem. I'll add a note.

Comment: For 1a obviously no: take $P(x)=A+x^2-x^4$ with huge $A>0$ and shift it so that one of the roots is at the origin.